# user add records to database PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

> I wish to let a user add records to an empty database table. As a matter of fact I have a database and an empty table which has to be filled using a form 
>    the first file handles the db connection (I use **PDO**)returns an empty page and a link named add which goes to a form

```html
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
?>
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "xxx";
$password = "xxx";
$dbname = "xxxx";

try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
 echo 'Connected to database<br />';
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
?>
<html>
 <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Tages database</title>
 <style type="text/css">
 th { background-color: #999;}
 .odd_row { background-color: #EEE; }
 .even_row { background-color: #FFF; }
 </style>
 </head>
 <body>
    <table style="width: 100%;">
      <tr>
       <th colspan="2">Tages <a href="./tages.php?action=add"> [ADD]</a></th>
   </tr>
 <?php
**EDIT** 
>I have just replaced the `query` statement with prepare`      
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM tagesroma"); 

 
 $odd = true;
 while ($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  echo ($odd == true) ? '<tr class="odd_row">' : '<tr class="even_row">';
  $odd = !$odd;
  echo '<td style="width:75%;">';
  echo $row['nome'];
  echo '</td><td>';
  echo ' <a href="tages.php?action=edit&id=' . $row['id'] . '">
[EDIT]</a>';
     echo ' <a href="delete.php?type=tages&id=' . $row['id'] . '">
[DELETE]</a>';
     echo '<td></tr>';
 }
 ?>
 </table>
 </body>
 </html>
```

> the second page loads a form that once filled in points to a third and last page which make the user sure that everything went good

```html
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
?>
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "xxxx";
$password = "xxxxx";
$dbname = "xxxx";

try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
 echo 'Connected to database<br />';
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
?>
<?php
if ($_GET['action'] == 'edit') {
    //retrieve the record's information 
     **EDIT**
     I have just replaced `query` statement with `prepare`

    $sth = $dbh->prepare = 'SELECT
            nome, cognome, indirizzo, civico, citta,
            prov
        FROM
            tagesroma
        WHERE
            id = ' . $_GET['id'];
    $result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
} else {
    //set values to blank
    $nome = '';
    $cognome = '';
    $indirizzo = '';
    $civico = 0;
    $citta = '';
    $prov = '';
}
?>
<html>
 <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title><?php echo ucfirst($_GET['action']); ?> Tages</title>
  <style type="text/css">
  <!--
  #error { background-color: #600; border: 1px solid #FF0; color: #FFF;
   text-align: center; margin: 10px; padding: 10px; }
  -->
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <?php
   if (isset($_GET['error']) && $_GET['error'] != '') {
    echo '<div id="error">' . $_GET['error'] . '</div>';
   }
  ?>
  <form action="commit.php?action=<?php echo $_GET['action']; ?>&type=tages"
     method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">
> I have edited the form fields adding `value` to every `input`. The `value` echoes a variable that corresponds to the name of the `input` `label`
   <table>
    <tr>
     <td>Nome</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="nome" value="<?php echo $nome; ?>"/></td>
   </tr><tr>
    <td>Cognome</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="cognome" value="<?php echo $cognome; ?>"/></td>
   </tr><tr>
    <td>Indirizzo</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="indirizzo" value="<?php echo $indirizzo; ?>"/></td>
   </tr><tr>
    <td>Civico</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="civico" value="<?php echo $civico; ?>"/></td>
   </tr><tr>
    <td>Citta</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="citta" value="<?php echo $citta; ?>"/></td>
   </tr><tr>
    <td>Prov</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="prov" value="<?php echo $prov; ?>"/></td> 
    </tr><tr>
     <td colspan="2" style="text-align: center;">
     <?php
      if ($_GET['action'] == 'edit') {
       echo '<input type="hidden" value="' . $_GET['id'] . '" name="id" />';
      }
     ?>
     <input type="submit" name="submit"
                    value="<?php echo ucfirst($_GET['action']); ?>" />
     </td>
    </tr>
   </table>
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

> the third one is a confirmation page that aforementioned check whether errors occure and if everything goes good in the first page you should see the just addeed record

```html
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
?>
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "xxxx";
$password = "xxxxx";
$dbname = "xxxx";

try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
 echo 'Connected to database<br />';
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
 > **EDIT** I have just replaced the `query` statement with `prepare`
    $dbh->prepare("use accessibilita"); 

?>
<?php
switch ($_GET['action']) {
case 'add':
    switch ($_GET['type']) {
    case 'tages':
        $error = array();
        $nome = isset($_POST['nome']) ?
            trim($_POST['nome']) : '';
        if (empty($nome)) {
            $error[] = urlencode('Si prega di inserire un nome.');
        }
        $cognome = isset($_POST['cognome']) ?
            trim($_POST['cognome']) : '';
        if (empty($cognome)) {
            $error[] = urlencode('Si prega di inserire un cognome.');
        }
        $indirizzo = isset($_POST['indirizzo']) ?
            trim($_POST['indirizzo']) : '';
        if (empty($indirizzo)) {
            $error[] = urlencode('Si prega di inserire un indirizzo.');
        }
        $civico = isset($_POST['civico']) ?
            trim($_POST['civico']) : '';
        if (empty($civico)) {
            $error[] = urlencode('Si prega di inserire un numero civico.');
        }
        $citta = isset($_POST['citta']) ?
        trim($_POST['citta']) : '';
    if (empty($citta)) {
        $error[] = urlencode('Si prega di inserire una citta.'); //citta just added
    }
        $prov = isset($_POST['prov']) ?
            trim($_POST['prov']) : '';
        if (empty($prov)) {
            $error[] = urlencode('Si prega di inserire una provincia.');
        }
        if (empty($error)) {
            > **EDIT** I have just replaced the `query` statement with `prepare`    
          $prepare= 'INSERT INTO 
                tagesroma
                    (nome, cognome, indirizzo, civico,
                    citta, prov)
                VALUES
                    ("' . $nome . '",
                     ' . $cognome . ',
                     ' . $indirizzo . ',
                     ' . $civico . ',
                     ' . $citta . ',
                     ' . $prov . ')';
        } else {
          header('Location:tages.php?action=add' .
              '&error=' . join($error, urlencode('<br/>')));
        }
        break;
    }
    break;
case 'edit':
    switch ($_GET['type']) {
    case 'tages':
        $error = array();
        $nome = isset($_POST['nome']) ?
            trim($_POST['nome']) : '';
        if (empty($nome)) {
            $error[] = urlencode('Si prega di inserire un nome.');
        }
        $cognome = isset($_POST['cognome']) ?
            trim($_POST['cognome']) : '';
        if (empty($cognome)) {
            $error[] = urlencode('Si prega di inserire un cognome.');
        }
        $indirizzo = isset($_POST['indirizzo']) ?
            trim($_POST['indirizzo']) : '';
        if (empty($indirizzo)) {
            $error[] = urlencode('Si prega di inserire un indirizzo.');
        }
        $civico = isset($_POST['civico']) ?
            trim($_POST['civico']) : '';
        if (empty($civico)) {
            $error[] = urlencode('Si prega di inserire un numero civico.');
        }
         $citta= isset($_POST['citta']) ?
        trim($_POST['citta']) : '';
    if (empty($citta)) {
        $error[] = urlencode('Si prega di inserire una citta.'); //citta just added
    }
        $prov = isset($_POST['prov']) ?
            trim($_POST['prov']) : '';
        if (empty($prov)) {
            $error[] = urlencode('Si prega di inserire una provincia.');
        }
        if (empty($error)) {
            > **EDIT** I have just replaced the `query` statement with `prepare` 
               $prepare= 'UPDATE
                    tagesroma
                SET 
                    nome = "' . $nome . '",
                    cognome = ' . $cognome . ',
                    indirizzo = ' . $indirizzo . ',
                    civico = ' . $civico . ',
                    citta = ' . $citta . ',
                    prov = ' . $prov . ' //variable replacement 
                WHERE
                    id = ' . $_POST['id'];
        } else {
          header('Location:tages.php?action=edit&id=' . $_POST['id'] .
              '&error=' . join($error, urlencode('<br/>')));
        }
        break;
    }
    break;
}
?>

<html>
 <head>
  <title>Commit</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
 </head>
 <body>
  <p>Done!</p>
 </body>
</html>
```

> in every page the `error reporting` is enabled but no error is returned and I am unable to add records to my table
>   in the third page I have created an `array` named error which handles the validation of the fields of the form. Whenever I try to insert the needed data to fill in the form the validation returns that I need to insert a `name` in order to go to the last step `commit.php` (the page that checks whether the entered data are correct and if so adds a new record to the main page `admin.php`). I have fixed the validation issue and now the error returned is the following: `Notice: Undefined variable: citta commit.php(third page) on line 64`
>   I have just been able to define the `variable: citta` but still no record has been successfully added

Comment: Your 3rd script defines a variable `$query` and does nothing with it. You also use PDO but I see no prepared statements. If you stick that `$query` variable in `$pdo->query()` then you will be susceptible to SQL injection.

Comment: @N.B  So could you provide me an answer as a possible solution to help me to fix my problem

Comment: You mean a copy paste example? You got this far on your own, you're using PDO, you set it into exception mode, you managed to issue a query.. you are 2 lines of code away from using a prepared statement and executing it. [Here are examples](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) that you can literally copypaste and change with your column names and variables.

Comment: So your suggestion is to use prepare rather then query am I right???

Comment: Only when the former variable query is equals to UPDATE?? Or even in the code above inside the connection handler???

Comment: When you have to pass user input to a query, you use a prepared statement. That means for insert, select or update you use a prepared statement **if you must pass user-supplied information to the query**.

Comment: @N.B. could you please tell me if inside my `while loop` (in the third page)makes difference  to state `switch` `add` `case`: `tages`or `tagesroma`(as `case`) because when I use `tages` the form validation tells me to write the correct name but I did write the correct name. I hope to have been clear enough for you to understand me

Comment: @N.B. I have discovered a very important thing as a matter of fact whenever I use the `case` `tages` for both add and edit and I send the form without filling the fields the validation blocks runs and tells me to fill in the fields of the form this means the right `case` to use is `tages` but when I proceed and fill in all of the fields the form can not be sent and I am asked to type the name again endlessly