# pdo to retrieve data and populate a record

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

> I have already asked a question about PDO [user add records to database PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31561478/user-add-records-to-database-pdo), now I am unable to select data and insert them into a html form in order to allow a user what to choose and as a consequence to add record into a db table

```html
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
?>
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "xxx";
$password = "xxx";
$dbname = "xxx";

try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
 echo 'Connected to database<br />';
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
?>
<?php
if ($_GET['action'] == 'edit') {
    //retrieve the record's information 
   $sth = $dbh->prepare = 'SELECT
            nome, cognome, indirizzo, civico, citta,
            prov
        FROM
            tagesroma
        WHERE
            id = ' . $_GET['id'];
    $sth = $dbh->execute();
 extract($sth = $dbh->fetch());
    } else {
    //set values to blank
    $nome = '';
    $cognome = '';
    $indirizzo = '';
    $civico = 0;
    $citta = '';
    $prov = '';
}
?>
<html>
 <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title><?php echo ucfirst($_GET['action']); ?> Tages</title>
  <style type="text/css">
  <!--
  #error { background-color: #600; border: 1px solid #FF0; color: #FFF;
   text-align: center; margin: 10px; padding: 10px; }
  -->
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <?php
   if (isset($_GET['error']) && $_GET['error'] != '') {
    echo '<div id="error">' . $_GET['error'] . '</div>';
   }
  ?>
  <form action="commit.php?action=<?php echo $_GET['action']; ?>&type=tages"
     method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">
   <table>
    <tr>
     <td>Nome</td>
     <td><input type="text" name="nome" value="<?php echo $nome; ?>"/></td>
    </tr><tr>
     <td>Cognome</td>
     <td><select name="cognome"></td>
     <?php
     //seleziona il tipo di cognome
     $sth = $dbh->prepare = 'SELECT
          cognome
      FROM
      tagesroma';
                    $sth->execute();
                    //popola con i risultati
                    while ($row = $sth->fetch()) {
      foreach ($dbh->$row as $value) {
       if ($row['id'] == $cognome) {
        echo '<option value="' . $row['id'] .
        '" selected="selected">';
       } else {
        echo '<option value="' . $row['id'] . '">';
       }
      }
                    }
                    ?> 
                </select></td>     
    </tr><tr>
     <td colspan="2" style="text-align: center;">
     <?php
      if ($_GET['action'] == 'edit') {
       echo '<input type="hidden" value="' . $_GET['id'] . '" name="id" />'; 
      }
     ?>
     <input type="submit" name="submit"
                    value="<?php echo ucfirst($_GET['action']); ?>" />
     </td>
    </tr>
   </table>
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

> the error I am dealing with is the following:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object on line 76
```

Comment: Do not close your PHP tags until HTML output begins, otherwise you will experience 'Headers already sent' errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error `Call to a member function execute() on a non-object` means this area of the code is invalid:

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare = 'SELECT
        nome, cognome, indirizzo, civico, citta,
        prov
    FROM
        tagesroma
    WHERE
        id = ' . $_GET['id'];
$sth = $dbh->execute();
```

The correct way is:

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("
  SELECT nome, cognome, indirizzo, civico, citta, prov
  FROM   tagesroma
  WHERE  id = ?
");
$sth->execute(array($_GET['id']));
```

- Use double-quote if you want to use newlines
- Know that `prepare()` is a function, so following it with `=` doesn't make sense
- Tidy your code for readability

Comment: and what about `else` condition just below the query

Comment: @Riccardo990 I am not sure what you're asking, but it looks like you should be using an array as opposed to lots of variables.

Comment: SO YOUR suggestion is to eliminate the  `else`

Comment: @Riccardo990 `else` is usually a good idea -- if you have another question please start a new thread. If my answer fixed the execute error then please mark this answer as accepted.

Comment: i will try your answer and let you as soon as possible just in a few minutes

Comment: @Riccardo990 If you ask a new question we can all help you :)

Comment: I must wait 90 minutes my friend

Comment: this is the link to my new quiestion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31653752/validation-and-data-add-to-a-db-table?noredirect=1#comment51252684_31653752 please look it up

Answer (score 0):

You are not using prepared statements properly. try this:

```
   <?php 

   $id = $_GET['id'];

   $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT
        nome, cognome, indirizzo, civico, citta,
        prov
    FROM
        tagesroma
    WHERE
        id =  :id");

   $sth->bindParam(":id",$id,PDO::PARAM_INT);


  $sth->execute();


   ?>
```

Comment: Creating the `$id` variable is unnecessary.