# validation and data add to a db table

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

the questions I have asked earlier 
[pdo to retrieve data and populate a record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31650860/pdo-to-retrieve-data-and-populate-a-record?noredirect=1#comment51247635_31650860) was about the input mask now i need to validate the user input and add what has been entered to a db table and this is the very last step.

My mistake is as you can see in the below code that I misinterpret the **INSERT INTO** and **UPDATE SET** using **PDO**.

Furthermore as far as concerned with `INSERT INTO` I do use `bindParam` in order to attempt a data entry, while about the `UPDATE SET` I use `execute(array)`. As a matter of fact this code validates the user data input and whether that input is correct php attempts to connect to db and should insert into or update a table. The strange part is that no error is returned and no data is added

```html
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
?>
<?php
$servername = "xxx";
$username = "xx";
$password = "xxx";
$dbname = "xxxx";

try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
 echo 'Connected to database<br />';
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
 $sth = $dbh->prepare("use accessibilita");
?>
<?php
switch ($_GET['action']) {
case 'add':
switch ($_GET['type']) {
case 'tages':
    $error = array();
    $nome = isset($_POST['nome']) ?
        trim($_POST['nome']) : '';
    if (empty($nome)) {
        $error[] = urlencode('Si prega di inserire un nome.');
    }
    $cognome = isset($_POST['cognome']) ?
        trim($_POST['cognome']) : '';
    if (empty($cognome)) {
        $error[] = urlencode('Si prega di inserire un cognome.');
    }
    $indirizzo = isset($_POST['indirizzo']) ?
        trim($_POST['indirizzo']) : '';
    if (empty($indirizzo)) {
        $error[] = urlencode('Si prega di inserire un indirizzo.');
    }
    $civico = isset($_POST['civico']) ?
        trim($_POST['civico']) : '';
    if (empty($civico)) {
        $error[] = urlencode('Si prega di inserire un numero civico.');
    }
 $citta = isset($_POST['citta']) ?
        trim($_POST['citta']) : '';
    if (empty($citta)) {
        $error[] = urlencode('Si prega di inserire una citta valida.');
    }
    $prov = isset($_POST['prov']) ?
        trim($_POST['prov']) : '';
    if (empty($prov)) {
        $error[] = urlencode('Si prega di inserire una provincia.');
    }
    if (empty($error)) {
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO tagesroma(nome, cognome, indirizzo, civico, citta, prov)
            VALUES (:nome, :cognome, :indirizzo, :civico, :citta, :prov)");
   $stmt->bindParam(':nome', $nome);
   $stmt->bindParam(':cognome', $cognome);
   $stmt->bindParam(':indirizzo', $indirizzo);
   $stmt->bindParam(':civico', $civico);
   $stmt->bindParam(':citta', $citta);
   $stmt->bindParam(':prov', $prov);
    } else {
      header('Location:tages.php?action=add' .
          '&error=' . join($error, urlencode('<br/>')));
    }
    break;
}
break;
case 'edit':
switch ($_GET['type']) {
case 'tages':
    $error = array();
    $nome = isset($_POST['nome']) ?
        trim($_POST['nome']) : '';
    if (empty($nome)) {
        $error[] = urlencode('Si prega di inserire un nome.');
    }
    $cognome = isset($_POST['cognome']) ?
        trim($_POST['cognome']) : '';
    if (empty($cognome)) {
        $error[] = urlencode('Si prega di inserire un cognome.');
    }
    $indirizzo = isset($_POST['indirizzo']) ?
        trim($_POST['indirizzo']) : '';
    if (empty($indirizzo)) {
        $error[] = urlencode('Si prega di inserire un indirizzo.');
    }
    $civico = isset($_POST['civico']) ?
        trim($_POST['civico']) : '';
    if (empty($civico)) {
        $error[] = urlencode('Si prega di inserire un numero civico.');
    }
 $citta = isset($_POST['citta']) ?
        trim($_POST['citta']) : '';
    if (empty($citta)) {
        $error[] = urlencode('Si prega di inserire una citta valida.');
    }
    $prov = isset($_POST['prov']) ?
        trim($_POST['prov']) : '';
    if (empty($prov)) {
        $error[] = urlencode('Si prega di inserire una provincia.');
    }
    if (empty($error)) {
     //SYNTAX ERROR CORRECTION 
      $stmt = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE tagesroma SET nome=?, cognome=?, indirizzo=?, civico=?, citta=?, prov=?)");
   $stmt->execute(array($nome, $cognome, $indirizzo, $civico, $citta, $prov)); 
    } else {
      header('Location:tages.php?action=edit&id=' . $_POST['id'] .
          '&error=' . join($error, urlencode('<br/>')));
    }
    break;
}
break;
}
?>

<html>
 <head>
  <title>Commit</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
 </head>
 <body>
  <p>Done!</p>
 </body>
</html>
```

**Update/edit:**

I did correct the `UPDATE SET` part but still no data is added

Comment: this will fail for one thing `UPDATE tagesroma SET nome?, cognome?, indirizzo?, civico?, citta?, prov?` and probably even *silently*.

Comment: your UPDATE/SET syntax is incorrect. Read up on it https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html

Comment: and what about my `INSERT INTO` syntax?

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: in the above snippet of code actually there is an`error reporting` enabled

Comment: I have a hard time to figure out just what the problem is here. You say in your question that you're unable to establish a PDO connection. If so, then either your conditional statements are failing or you're not connected to your server.

Comment: I have badly written my question as a matter of fact I just meant that I am unable to handle the `INSERT INTO` and `UPDATE` I do apologize for disturbing thee my friend. I will immediately correct my question

Comment: no problema mi amico. see my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you never executed for the INSERT

Add this to it:

```
$stmt -> execute();
```

which is why no errors return, because there are none; just something "missing" ;-)

Reference:

- http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements

Comment: than you my friend you literally saved my day if you need anything just ask :)

Comment: @Riccardo990 prego. forse un cappuccino? ;-) *arrivederla*

Comment: sei italiano? sono abituato a scrivere in inglese che  bella sorpresa se ti trovi a Roma volentieri

Comment: @Riccardo990 no, sono francese. parlano un po, e studiare la lingua per un anno all'incirca.

Comment: @Riccardo990 dunque, ho capito la vostra questione/code ;-)

Comment: may you give me your email so that we can keep talking because another problem has occured and it would be better whether we move this discussion to chat or we email each other because your answer is correct and this is a new problem

Comment: je te remercie pour tout les chose que tu as fait mon ami, donc nous chat ou nous nous envoyons email?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84374/discussion-between-riccardo990-and-fred-ii).

Comment: @Riccardo990 visitate il mio profile. my website is there. I have links you can contact me in, but it's not user-friendly though. It's a way for me to make sure that people who send me a message, must verify their email address and I've mentioned a few things in there in regards to our Canadian anti-spam law ;-) I am not saying you're a spammer but I have to protect my website from others who are. *arrivederci!*

Comment: Fred I've just visited your website but there is no email I'm on my iPhone now and I had to quit the chat can you send me your email???

Comment: @Riccardo990 follow the links where it says "Say hello back"

Comment: @Riccardo990 question is... did you? - *occhietto*

Comment: Ahahah no it isn't I just wanted to know whether you received the email I sent to you because I am afraid to have mistyped the required fields of your website in order to be able to send you an email

Comment: @Riccardo990 check your spam. Mail doesn't go through my db unless it's been verified and you should have received an email. plus we can't chat here. moderators will close us down.

Comment: No I didn't receive anything