# Unable to edit record from a table PDO PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a list of record each and everyone may be edited. Whenever the user click edit an input mask appears where new data need to be entered in order to replace the old ones. I use **PDO** to handle the database connection and I strongly believe the problem is that I can't **update** the existing table

Here is a link to my older post [validation and data add to a db table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31653752/validation-and-data-add-to-a-db-table)

The first snippet of code creates a form where the user enters some data.

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
?>
<?php
$servername = "xxxx";
$username = "xxxx";
$password = "xxxxx";
$dbname = "xxxxx";

try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
?>
<?php
if ($_GET['action'] == 'edit') {
    //retrieve the record's information 
   $sth = $dbh->prepare("
  SELECT nome, cognome, indirizzo, civico, citta, prov
  FROM   tagesroma
  WHERE  id = ?
");
$sth->execute(array($_GET['id']));
    } else {
    //set values to blank
    $nome = '';
    $cognome = '';
    $indirizzo = '';
    $civico = 0;
    $citta = '';
    $prov = '';
}
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title><?php echo ucfirst($_GET['action']); ?> Tages</title>
        <style type="text/css">
        <!--
        #error { background-color: #600; border: 1px solid #FF0; color: #FFF;
         text-align: center; margin: 10px; padding: 10px; }
        -->
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            if (isset($_GET['error']) && $_GET['error'] != '') {
                echo '<div id="error">' . $_GET['error'] . '</div>';
            }
        ?>
        <form action="commit.php?action=<?php echo $_GET['action']; ?>&type=tages"
           method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Nome</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name= "nome" value="<?php echo !empty($_POST['nome']) ? $_POST['nome'] : ''; ?>"></td>
                </tr><tr>
                    <td>Cognome</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name= "cognome" value="<?php echo !empty($_POST['cognome']) ? $_POST['cognome'] : ''; ?>"></td>                  
                </tr><tr>
                    <td>Indirizzo</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name= "indirizzo" value="<?php echo !empty($_POST['indirizzo']) ? $_POST['indirizzo'] : ''; ?>"></td>
                </tr><tr>
                    <td>Civico</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name= "civico" value="<?php echo !empty($_POST['civico']) ? $_POST['civico'] : ''; ?>"></td>
                </tr><tr>
                    <td>Citta</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name= "citta" value="<?php echo !empty($_POST['citta']) ? $_POST['citta'] : ''; ?>"></td>
                </tr><tr>
                    <td>Prov</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name= "prov" value="<?php echo !empty($_POST['prov']) ? $_POST['prov'] : ''; ?>"></td>
                </tr><tr>
                    <td colspan="2" style="text-align: center;">
                    <?php
                        if ($_GET['action'] == 'edit') {
                            echo '<input type="hidden" value="' . $_GET['id'] . '" name="id" />'; 
                        }
                    ?>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit"
                    value="<?php echo ucfirst($_GET['action']); ?>" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

The second part of the code validates the entered data and if and only if everything is correct then the new data are updated

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
?>
<?php
$servername = "xxx";
$username = "xxx";
$password = "xxxx";
$dbname = "xxxx";

try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
    $sth = $dbh->prepare("use accessibilita");
?>
<?php
 switch ($_GET['action']) {    
case 'edit':
    switch ($_GET['type']) {
    case 'tages':
        $error = array();
        $nome = isset($_POST['nome']) ?
            trim($_POST['nome']) : '';
        if (empty($nome)) {
            $error[] = urlencode('Si prega di inserire un nome.');
        }
        $cognome = isset($_POST['cognome']) ?
            trim($_POST['cognome']) : '';
        if (empty($cognome)) {
            $error[] = urlencode('Si prega di inserire un cognome.');
        }
        $indirizzo = isset($_POST['indirizzo']) ?
            trim($_POST['indirizzo']) : '';
        if (empty($indirizzo)) {
            $error[] = urlencode('Si prega di inserire un indirizzo.');
        }
        $civico = isset($_POST['civico']) ?
            trim($_POST['civico']) : '';
        if (empty($civico)) {
            $error[] = urlencode('Si prega di inserire un numero civico.');
        }
        $citta = isset($_POST['citta']) ?
            trim($_POST['citta']) : '';
        if (empty($citta)) {
            $error[] = urlencode('Si prega di inserire una citta valida.');
        }
        $prov = isset($_POST['prov']) ?
            trim($_POST['prov']) : '';
        if (empty($prov)) {
            $error[] = urlencode('Si prega di inserire una provincia.');
        }
        if (empty($error)) {
          $stmt = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE tagesroma SET nome=?, cognome=?, indirizzo=?, civico=?, citta=?, prov=? WHERE id=1");
          $stmt->execute(array($nome, $cognome, $indirizzo, $civico, $citta, $prov));         
        } else {
          header('Location:tages.php?action=edit&id=' . $_GET['id'] .
              '&error=' . join($error, urlencode('<br/>')));
        }
        break;
    }
    break;
}
?>

<html>
 <head>
  <title>Commit</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
 </head>
 <body>
  <p>Done!</p>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Put the prepare and execute in a TRY CATCH block and report any errors. Then you will probably see whats wrong

Comment: Pretty sure your form action is wrong.

Comment: You know what? Everything worked fine till today but now it doesn't this is absolutely frustrating

Comment: @RiggsFolly could you please provide me an answer or a suggestion? I'm unable now to work on the code

Comment: Please perform some debugging such that you can shorten your code example down only to the pertinent parts, as well as be able to better explain where code execution varies from what you expect.

Comment: `$stmt = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE tagesroma SET nome=?, cognome=?, indirizzo=?, civico=?, citta=?, prov=? WHERE id=1");` <-- this will only ever update record with id=1 -- is this what you intended?

Comment: If you look at the UPDATE part I clearly execute an array this is the point why an executed array can't execute??

Comment: @SteJ yes this is what I mean and below the code you'll see an execute array

Comment: I've just copied and pasted your code, created a suitable database and tested it and it seems to work fine to me! The only problem I can see is that, no matter what $_GET["id"] is set to, it will only ever alter the record with id=1 -- are you sure it shouldn't be `$stmt = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE tagesroma SET nome=?, cognome=?, indirizzo=?, civico=?, citta=?, prov=? WHERE id=".$_GET["id"]);` instead?

Comment: @SteJ this is absurd my db can't edit content yours does?!!!

Comment: Check your database permissions - maybe you don't have UPDATE permissions set for your db user?

Comment: So please post an answer with this suggestion so that if it is right I I will upvote that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84603/discussion-between-riccardo990-and-stej).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have re-created your code on my web server and it seems to work as you intended - *the only thing I changed was the login info for mysql*; whatever I type in your form updates the record with id=1 or generates an error message if data doesn't validate. Obviously I had to create a database matching your expected schema, so I just created all fields except id as VARCHAR(255).

I have a couple of suggestions to try:

1. Check that your database user has the UPDATE permission set
2. Check that the database does actually have a record with id=1 (it's feasible you've deleted and replaced the record and the id was changed by auto_increment?)

Hope this helps!

**EDIT: Having spoken to you, please see the following code which does what you want (on my server at least):

*tages.php:*

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
?>
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "redacted";
$password = "redacted";
$dbname = "test";

try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
?>
<?php
if ($_GET['action'] == 'edit') {
    //retrieve the record's information 
   $sth = $dbh->prepare("
  SELECT nome, cognome, indirizzo, civico, citta, prov
  FROM   tagesroma
  WHERE  id = ?
");
$sth->execute(array($_GET['id']));
    } else {
    //set values to blank
    $nome = '';
    $cognome = '';
    $indirizzo = '';
    $civico = 0;
    $citta = '';
    $prov = '';
}
?>
$thisrecord=$sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title><?php echo ucfirst($_GET['action']); ?> Tages</title>
        <style type="text/css">
        <!--
        #error { background-color: #600; border: 1px solid #FF0; color: #FFF;
         text-align: center; margin: 10px; padding: 10px; }
        -->
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            if (isset($_GET['error']) && $_GET['error'] != '') {
                echo '<div id="error">' . $_GET['error'] . '</div>';
            }
        ?>
    <!-- NOTICE THE ADDITION TO THE END OF THE action= TO PASS THE ID ON TO YOUR SCRIPT -->
        <form action="commit.php?action=<?php echo $_GET['action']; ?>&type=tages&id=<?php echo $_GET["id"];?>"
           method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Nome</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name= "nome" value="<?php echo !empty($_POST['nome']) ? $_POST['nome'] : $thisrecord["nome"]; ?>"></td>
                </tr><tr>
                    <td>Cognome</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name= "cognome" value="<?php echo !empty($_POST['cognome']) ? $_POST['cognome'] : $thisrecord["cognome"]; ?>"></td>                  
                </tr><tr>
                    <td>Indirizzo</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name= "indirizzo" value="<?php echo !empty($_POST['indirizzo']) ? $_POST['indirizzo'] : $thisrecord["indirizzo"]; ?>"></td>
                </tr><tr>
                    <td>Civico</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name= "civico" value="<?php echo !empty($_POST['civico']) ? $_POST['civico'] : $thisrecord["civico"]; ?>"></td>
                </tr><tr>
                    <td>Citta</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name= "citta" value="<?php echo !empty($_POST['citta']) ? $_POST['citta'] : $thisrecord["citta"]; ?>"></td>
                </tr><tr>
                    <td>Prov</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name= "prov" value="<?php echo !empty($_POST['prov']) ? $_POST['prov'] : $sth["prov"]; ?>"></td>
                </tr><tr>
                    <td colspan="2" style="text-align: center;">
                    <?php
                        if ($_GET['action'] == 'edit') {
                            echo '<input type="hidden" value="' . $_GET['id'] . '" name="id" />'; 
                        }
                    ?>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit"
                    value="<?php echo ucfirst($_GET['action']); ?>" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

*commit.php:*

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
?>
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "redacted";
$password = "redacted";
$dbname = "test";

try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
    $sth = $dbh->prepare("use accessibilita");
?>
<?php
 switch ($_GET['action']) {    
case 'edit':
    switch ($_GET['type']) {
    case 'tages':
        $error = array();
        $nome = isset($_POST['nome']) ?
            trim($_POST['nome']) : '';
        if (empty($nome)) {
            $error[] = urlencode('Si prega di inserire un nome.');
        }
        $cognome = isset($_POST['cognome']) ?
            trim($_POST['cognome']) : '';
        if (empty($cognome)) {
            $error[] = urlencode('Si prega di inserire un cognome.');
        }
        $indirizzo = isset($_POST['indirizzo']) ?
            trim($_POST['indirizzo']) : '';
        if (empty($indirizzo)) {
            $error[] = urlencode('Si prega di inserire un indirizzo.');
        }
        $civico = isset($_POST['civico']) ?
            trim($_POST['civico']) : '';
        if (empty($civico)) {
            $error[] = urlencode('Si prega di inserire un numero civico.');
        }
        $citta = isset($_POST['citta']) ?
            trim($_POST['citta']) : '';
        if (empty($citta)) {
            $error[] = urlencode('Si prega di inserire una citta valida.');
        }
        $prov = isset($_POST['prov']) ?
            trim($_POST['prov']) : '';
        if (empty($prov)) {
            $error[] = urlencode('Si prega di inserire una provincia.');
        }
        if (empty($error)) {
          $stmt = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE tagesroma SET nome=?, cognome=?, indirizzo=?, civico=?, citta=?, prov=? WHERE id=?"); // changed to WHERE id=?
          $stmt->execute(array($nome, $cognome, $indirizzo, $civico, $citta, $prov,$_GET["id"])); // added $_GET["id"] to the end        
        } else {
          header('Location:tages.php?action=edit&id=' . $_GET['id'] .
              '&error=' . join($error, urlencode('<br/>')));
        }
        break;
    }
    break;
}
?>

<html>
 <head>
  <title>Commit</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
 </head>
 <body>
  <p>Done!</p>
 </body>
</html>
```

Take a minute to have a look at the changes -- it turned out your problem was that it always edited the record with id=1 regardless of what record you'd selected for editing; this updated code adds the bits you were missing to pass the id of the "currently being edited" record.

**Further edit**: At your request I've altered tages.php to show the results of the query you have at the top. You already have $sth either set with the current values or initialised how they should be, and you also had the !empty?  there - all you needed to do was put the two together.

Comment: This is a very useful answer I would like to ask you whether we can move this discussion to chat because I need to talk to you about another issue do you agree?

Comment: So am I allowed to move this discussion to chat??

Comment: hey i can't move this discussion to chat

Comment: You should be in the room let me know

Comment: server error when I tried it let me know when you have something

Answer (score 0):

```
$errors = $stmt->errorInfo();
    foreach ($errors as $error) {
        echo $error ,'<br />';
    }
```

you can use above code to find what error you getting

Comment: this will show errors if you getting any in query execution

Answer (score 0):

Add some error processing code.

You set PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION so errors should throw an exception.

Here

```
if (!empty($error)) {
    header('Location:tages.php?action=edit&id=' . $_GET['id'] . '&error=' . join($error, urlencode('<br/>')));
    exit;
}

try {
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE tagesroma SET nome=?, cognome=?, indirizzo=?, civico=?, citta=?, prov=? WHERE id=1");
    $stmt->execute(array($nome, $cognome, $indirizzo, $civico, $citta, $prov));         
}
catch ( PDOException $e ) {
    echo 'INSERT FAILED WITH: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}
catch( Exception $ex ) {
    echo 'Some other error ' . $ex->getMessage();
    exit;
}
```

Comment: I'll try it as soon as I'm home and will let you know how it goes